# How do i fix 'Target class [App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts] does not exist' in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-10

My application always gives me this error:

> Illuminate  \  Contracts  \  Container  \  BindingResolutionException
> PHP 8.1.10
> 10.28.0 Target class [App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts] does not exist.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', [ListingController::class, 'index']);
```

**Single Listing**

```
Route::get('/listings/{listing}', [ListingController::class, 'show']);
```

**app/http/kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
      * @var array<int, class-string|string>
    //  */
     protected $middleware = [
 \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
}
```

I tried installing composer dump-autoload through the terminal. Also, i tried adding middleware to my route:

```
Route::get('/', [ListingController::class, 'index'])->middleware('TrustHosts');
```

// Single Listing

```
Route::get('/listings/{listing}', [ListingController::class, 'show'])->middleware('TrustHosts');
```

I tried checking for any typo errors, but all in vain. Someone should help, please. Thank you.`